# How to extract coefficients of Jacobi polynomial using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials, coefficients

I'd like to consecutively plot the zeros of several Jacobi polynomials. The parameters and degree of the Jacobi polynomials depend on a certain size variable n. I want to compute the roots of each polynomial by first extracting the coefficients of the polynomial into an array. However, this cannot be done with the `coeffs()` command since the Jacobi polynomial is of class `sympy.core.add.Add`, which does not have `coeffs()` as an attribute. Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
init_printing()
x = Symbol("x")

def show_roots(n,a,b,c):
    for k in range (1,n+1):
        p = jacobi(a*k,-(a+b)*k,(b+c)*k,x)
        coeff = p.coeffs(x)
        roots = numpy.roots(coeff)
        plt.plot(roots)
        plt.show()
        plt.pause(3)
```

The error I am shown when I try out show_roots with specific values: 
`AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'coeffs'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `Add` to `Poly` first then call `coeffs()` on the result.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy
import numpy
x = sympy.symbols('x')

def show_roots(n,a,b,c):
    for k in range (1,n+1):
        p = sympy.jacobi(a*k,-(a+b)*k,(b+c)*k,x)        
        coeff = sympy.poly(p).coeffs()
        roots = numpy.roots(coeff)
        print(roots)

show_roots(3,1,2,3)
```

gives

```
[2.]
[2.+0.65465367j 2.-0.65465367j]
[2.24801968+0.j         1.87599016+0.92968658j 1.87599016-0.92968658j]
```

You can now do the plotting stuff.